# EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource fail to load image with the same name different subfolder in Eclipse (Blackberry plugin)

Tags: eclipse, image, plugins, blackberry

I'm using the Blackberry JDE Plugin v1.3 for Eclipse and I'm trying this code to create a BitmapField and I've always done it this way:

```
this.bitmap = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("ico_01.png");
this.bitmap = this.bitmap.scaleImage32(
                  this.conf.getWidthScale(), this.conf.getHeightScale());
this.imagenLoad = new BitmapField(this.bitmap.getBitmap(), this.style);
```

It works fine with no errors, but now I have this set of images with the same name but in different subfolders like this:

[image]

I made it smaller than it actually is for explanatory reasons. I wouldn't want to rename the files so they're all different. I would like to know how to access the different subfolders. "res/img/on/ico_01.jpg", "img/on/ico_01.jpg", "on/ico_01.jpg" are some examples that I tried and failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(filename)` will retrieve the first instance of `filename` *regardless of where it is in your resource directory tree*.

This is not very helpful if you have the images with the same filename in different directories (as you have).

The solution I have used is to create my own method which can return an image based on a path and filename.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromResource(String resourceFilename){

    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

    //get the image as a byte stream
    InputStream imageStream = getInstance().getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceFilename);
    //load it into memory
    byte imageBytes[];
    try {

        imageBytes = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(imageStream);
        //create the bitmap
        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length, 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.log("Error loading: "+resourceFilename+". "+e.getMessage());
    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```